# What pauper cards are legal in MTGO but not paper?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

I am trying to collect most cards relevant to pauper. All cards that have ever been printed at the common level on paper are legal for pauper, except for [10 cards on the pauper ban list](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/pauper).

Because MTGO pauper is more popular than paper pauper, and because it is so easily available electronically, it is easy to find data and analysis on the most frequently used cards in pauper. I did this.

The problem is that there are some cards, such as Chainer's Edict, that are common on MTGO but have never been printed as paper commons. They are therefore not legal for play with paper pauper.

Is there a list maintained of cards printed at common for MTGO, but not paper? If so, please provide link. If there is no such list but it turns out to be very few cards, then the answer should contain that short list of cards, followed by "as of x date."

Note: For the exact opposite list of cards, see: [What pauper cards are legal in paper but not MTGO](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25474/what-paper-pauper)

Comment: I would still count Chainer's Edict as allowed for paper aswell, because gatherer counts the Vintage Masters as a print aswell. The rules state : Example: Counterspell was a common card in Seventh Edition Core Set online. Counterspell was reprinted in Masters Edition II with an uncommon expansion symbol. Both versions of the card can now be used in pauper.

Comment: @Lyrion Can you think of a more clear example than Chainer's Edict to use in the question?

Comment: Hmm, not really. But to be fair, I would allow any common, even the mtgo only ones for paper pauper. A print is still a print even if it is online only.

Comment: -1. The question in its current form is not very useful, because the answers to it will quickly go out of date. A more useful question would be "**How can I find** what pauper cards are legal in MTGO but not paper?"

Comment: @Rainbolt The question does ask for a maintained list elsewhere if possible. If that doesn't exist and you ask how to find out, the answer is going to be "here are the online-only sets; check every common in them" which is in the end even less useful than an out of date answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a comprehensive breakdown of the differences between paper pauper and MTGO pauper here:

http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/the-game/other-formats/paper-pauper-and-peasant/662888-differences-between-mtgo-and-paper

There are 387 cards that have been printed as commons but aren't available as such online.

Answer (score 5):

I have a program that lets me do weird queries, this was an interesting one to code.  Here are the results:

```
Adarkar Sentinel                  Addle                             Aeolipile                         
Afterlife                         Alluring Scent                    Anaba Ancestor                    
Anaba Spirit Crafter              Armored Griffin                   Arrogant Wurm                     
Balduvian Conjurer                Barktooth Warbeard                Battle Screech                    
Beetleback Chief                  Bone Flute                        Brass Man                         
Brilliant Plan                    Brindle Shoat                     Chainer's Edict                   
Circular Logic                    Citanul Druid                     Claws of Wirewood                 
Coal Golem                        Dauthi Mercenary                  Death Spark                       
Demonic Torment                   Desperate Charge                  Drift of the Dead                 
Ebony Horse                       Elephant Guide                    Elven Lyre                        
Exile                             Fellwar Stone                     Feral Thallid                     
Fire Drake                        Flying Carpet                     Foul Spirit                       
Gilded Light                      Glasses of Urza                   Goblin Commando                   
Goblin Firestarter                Goblin General                    Gravebind                         
Heavy Fog                         Hunting Cheetah                   Hyalopterous Lemure               
Icatian Lieutenant                Icatian Phalanx                   Icequake                          
Icy Prison                        Ironhoof Ox                       Jedit Ojanen                      
Jerrard of the Closed Fist        Just Fate                         Killer Whale                      
Kjeldoran Elite Guard             Kjeldoran Skycaptain              Knights of Thorn                  
Kobold Taskmaster                 Lady Orca                         Lava Flow                         
Lesser Werewolf                   Library of Leng                   Lightning Blow                    
Mana Prism                        Mightstone                        Mistmoon Griffin                  
Oasis                             Obsianus Golem                    Ogre Taskmaster                   
Onulet                            Peach Garden Oath                 Phantasmal Forces                 
Phantasmal Mount                  Phantom Monster                   Predatory Nightstalker            
Primal Clay                       Ramirez DePietro                  Red Cliffs Armada                 
Righteous Avengers                River Merfolk                     Rockslide Ambush                  
Roots                             Royal Trooper                     Sea Sprite                        
Shield Sphere                     Shu Elite Companions              Shu General                       
Shu Soldier-Farmers               Shyft                             Sir Shandlar of Eberyn            
Sivitri Scarzam                   Skirge Familiar                   Skirk Drill Sergeant              
Slashing Tiger                    Sol Grail                         Soltari Emissary                  
Spoils of Victory                 Strategic Planning                Tangle                            
Tawnos's Wand                     Telekinesis                       Thallid Devourer                  
The Lady of the Mountain          Thermokarst                       Thrull Retainer                   
Tobias Andrion                    Torsten Von Ursus                 Tribute to the Wild               
Trip Wire                         Wall of Kelp                      Wall of Light                     
Wanderlust                        Warp Artifact                     Wei Elite Companions              
Whiteout                          Wu Longbowman
```

EDIT: forgot Tempest Remastered:

```
Armor Sliver                      Barbed Sliver                     Bottle Gnomes                     
Elven Rite                        Horned Sliver                     Mnemonic Sliver                   
Patchwork Gnomes                  Skyshaper                         Staunch Defenders                 
Telethopter                       Verdigris                         Whispers of the Muse
```

Comment: What's the logic/source data behind this list?

Comment: Query all cards in MED, ME2, ME3, ME4, and VMA, if the printing was at common, search all other printings, if no common printings were found, output the card name.

Comment: I think something didn't go quite right with the query. I asked a similar question on reddit a few hours ago, asking especially for cards that really matter. In addition to Chainer's Edict, other cards mentioned were Goblin Grenade, Desert, Pyrotechnics, and Sinkhole. Can you refine the query?

Comment: @JoeGolton Those cards you mentioned are common in their physical printings, but not in their virtual ones.  The list you're looking for is the opposite of that, right?  Cards that are common in virtual printings, but have no physial printings at common?

Comment: Yes you're right. I've been flipping back and forth between the two this morning and got it backwards. Thanks for the list!!

Comment: as a programmer, i'm interested: what are you using to run queries? do you have an sql-like relational database full of cards and info? where did you get your data dump? i ask because i frequently end up stymied by gatherer's extremely limited search criteria.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I have a java library I wrote that builds Card objects from JSON that contains all relevant game/printing information.  It's still in development (and I'm sort of taking a break from it right now) but it's in a sufficiently workable state that I can use it to do tasks like this.  I have it hosted [here on GitHub](https://github.com/c0d3br34k3r/magic), if you'd like to provide any feedback I'd certainly appreciate it!

Comment: neat! i'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

According to magiccards.info, the sets that were only "printed" online are MTGO Masters Edition I through IV and Vintage Masters. [This search page](http://magiccards.info/query?q=r%3Acommon%20%28e%3Avma%2Fen%20or%20e%3Ame4%2Fen%20or%20e%3Ame3%2Fen%20or%20e%3Ame2%2Fen%20or%20e%3Amed%2Fen%29&v=card&s=cname) lists all 376 cards that were printed as common in one of those sets. You can see on the right side of each card listing the rarities the cards were printed at in other sets. I haven't looked through the whole list, but as a sample, 7 of the 20 cards on the first page were only printed as commons online.

Comment: What about Tempest Remastered?

Comment: I don't know. magiccards.info doesn't have it in the list of sets to search.

Comment: They have to have been common in one of those 6 MTGO only sets, but uncommon or better in every other set, not all of the 376 commons from the 5 sets you checked are not pauper legal in paper due to other sets.