# What pauper cards are legal in paper but not MTGO

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

Note: This is exactly the opposite question of:

[What pauper cards are legal in MTGO but not paper?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25435/what-pauper-cards-are-legal-in-mtgo-but-not-paper)

I am trying to collect most cards relevant to pauper. Because MTGO pauper is more popular than paper pauper, and because it is so easily available electronically, it is easy to find data and analysis on the most frequently used cards in pauper. I did this.

The problem is that there are some cards (most notably Hymn to Tourach and High Tide) not available on MTGO but available as paper commons. Other popular pauper cards include Goblin Grenade, Desert, Pyrotechnics, and Sinkhole. They are easy to miss when starting a paper pauper collection, though I suppose you'd eventually come across them in pauper tournaments.

The pauper format continues to grow in popularity so perhaps Wizards of the Coast will eventually develop official rulings on this. Some people feel that any common card in either MTGO or paper should be legal. However, for now, many local stores only allow paper commons.

The question:

Is there a list maintained of cards printed at common for paper, but not MTGO? If so, please provide link. If there is no such list but it turns out to be very few cards, then the answer should contain the list of cards.

Comment: Why not just ask "What are the differences in cards legal in paper pauper vs MTGO pauper?" instead of keeping them as two seperate questions?

Comment: @waterseas I think the answers would be less clear and too long.

Comment: -1. The question in its current form is not very useful, because the answers to it will quickly go out of date. A more useful question would be "How can I find what pauper cards are legal in paper but not MTGO?"

Comment: @rainbolt As Jefromi stated in a comment to the sister question, this question asks for a maintained list elsewhere if possible. If that doesn't exist and you ask how to find out, the answer is going to be "here are the online-only sets; check every common in them" which is in the end even less useful than an out of date answer. Regardless, the question will likely be obsolete at some point when Wizards of the Coast takes an official stand on paper pauper, which is gradually becoming more popular. Until then, a list, even moderately out of date, is useful when building a collection.

Comment: @JoeGolton At worst, it'll be two seperated lists as an answer. At best, the answer will be the same for the two, or just a minor tweak, if it's a link or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a comprehensive breakdown of the differences between paper pauper and MTGO pauper here:

http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/the-game/other-formats/paper-pauper-and-peasant/662888-differences-between-mtgo-and-paper

There are 129 cards that are common online but have never been phsyically printed at that rarity.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering_Online), all sets since (and including) "Invasion" have been released on MTGO. This means the Masques, Urza, Tempest, Mirage, (most of) Ice Age, and Homelands blocks are not included in MTGO. In addition, core sets up until 6th edition and the Alpha, Beta, Unlimited, Arabian Nights, Antiquities, Revised, Legends, The Dark, and Fallen Empires expansions are also excluded from MTGO.

Rather than searching gatherer for these sets, it is better to exclude the sets that *are* in MTGO, because that will exclude cards from early sets that got re-printed in later sets.

As of the release of Magic Origins, the following gatherer search should provide a list of all commons that were only printed in the sets before MTGO was released.

shortened url: http://goo.gl/O8OdKM

full url:

```
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&set=+![%22Magic%20Origins%22]+![%22Seventh%20Edition%22]+![%22Eighth%20Edition%22]+![%22Ninth%20Edition%22]+![%22Tenth%20Edition%22]+![%22Magic%202010%22]+![%22Magic%202011%22]+![%22Magic%202012%22]+![%22Magic%202013%22]+![%22Magic%202014%20Core%20Set%22]+![%22Magic%202015%20Core%20Set%22]+![%22Invasion%22]+![%22Planeshift%22]+![%22Apocalypse%22]+![%22Odyssey%22]+![%22Torment%22]+![%22Judgment%22]+![%22Onslaught%22]+![%22Legions%22]+![%22Scourge%22]+![%22Mirrodin%22]+![%22Darksteel%22]+![%22Fifth%20Dawn%22]+![%22Champions%20of%20Kamigawa%22]+![%22Betrayers%20of%20Kamigawa%22]+![%22Saviors%20of%20Kamigawa%22]+![%22Ravnica:%20City%20of%20Guilds%22]+![%22Guildpact%22]+![%22Coldsnap%22]+![%22Time%20Spiral%22]+![%22Planar%20Chaos%22]+![%22Future%20Sight%22]+![%22Lorwyn%22]+![%22Morningtide%22]+![%22Shadowmoor%22]+![%22Eventide%22]+![%22Shards%20of%20Alara%22]+![%22Conflux%22]+![%22Alara%20Reborn%22]+![%22Zendikar%22]+![%22Worldwake%22]+![%22Rise%20of%20the%20Eldrazi%22]+![%22Scars%20of%20Mirrodin%22]+![%22Mirrodin%20Besieged%22]+![%22New%20Phyrexia%22]+![%22Innistrad%22]+![%22Dark%20Ascension%22]+![%22Avacyn%20Restored%22]+![%22Return%20to%20Ravnica%22]+![%22Gatecrash%22]+![%22Dragon%27s%20Maze%22]+![%22theros%22]+![%22Born%20of%20the%20Gods%22]+![%22Journey%20into%20Nyx%22]+![%22Khans%20of%20Tarkir%22]+![%22Fate%20Reforged%22]+![%22Dragons%20of%20Tarkir%22]&rarity=+[C]
```

---

*Edit: Looking at the results, it looks like the query wasn't perfect. But it's a good start.*

Comment: The query isn't excluding cards printed in those sets.  Plenty of M15 cards and similar are showing.  I'm trying to figure out how to fix it, but I don't think I can through gatherer.

Comment: @dragoncmd I don't think either gatherer or magiccards.info has a way to search for cards at 2 different rarities. At least I tried using their versions of if(rarity = common && rarity != common) and got 0 results for both of them.